# MVVM binding, get previous form values before saving

Tags: java, mvvm, data-binding, viewmodel, zk

## Problem

I have a `Person` object, that can be edited in a popup window.

I need to know, when the **form is saved**, if some **values have changed**.

I am using a **global variable** to store the **initial state** of the object but it seems that variable is **updated too** and I don't understand why.

---

## Code

Take a look at the code, it is more explicit (I have removed irrelevant code so it is easier to read) :

**Model** (*Person.java*) :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

    @Column
    private String lastName;

    @Column
    private String firstName;

}
```

**View model** (*PersonVm.java*) :

```
@VariableResolver(org.zkoss.zkplus.spring.DelegatingVariableResolver.class)
public class PersonVm {

    private Person person;
    private static Person initialPerson;
    private PersonGroupingVm personGroupingModel;

    @Init
    public void init(@ExecutionArgParam("person") Person pers, @ContextParam(ContextType.VIEW) Component view) {
        Selectors.wireComponents(view, this, false);
        if (pers != null) 
            person = pers;
        setPersonGroupingModel(new PersonGroupingVm(personMgr.getPersons(), new PersonComparator(), false));
    }

    @Command
    @NotifyChange("person")
    public void openEditPersonDialog(@BindingParam("person") Person pers) {
        initialPerson = pers;
        Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        args.put("person", pers);
        Executions.createComponents(".../editPerson.zul", null, args);
    }

    @Command
    @NotifyChange("person")
    public void savePerson() {
        Clients.alert(person.equals(initialPerson) + "");
        Clients.alert(person.getFirstName());
        Clients.alert(initialPerson.getFirstName());
        // person and initialPerson both contain new values !
    }

}
```

**View** (*persons.zul*) :

```
<vlayout apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" viewModel="@id('vm') @init('ch.myorg.vm.PersonVm')">
    <grid model="@load(vmp.personGroupingModel)">
        ...
        <template name="model" var="pers">
            <row>
                <label value="@load(pers.firstName)"/>
                <label value="@load(pers.lastName)"/>
                <button onClick="@command('openEditPersonDialog', person=pers)"/>
            </row>
        </template>
    </grid>
</vlayout>
```

**View** (*editPersonDialog.zul*) :

```
<window apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" viewModel="@id('vm') @init('ch.myorg.vm.PersonVm')">
    <div form="@id('p') @load(vm.person) @save(vm.person, before='savePerson')">
        <textbox value="@bind(p.firstName)"/>
        <textbox value="@bind(p.lastName)"/>
        <button label="${labels.action.validate}" onClick="@command('savePerson')"/>
    </div>
</window>
```

Why did my 2 objects (`person` and `initialPerson`) contain the new values? Only the `person` object is bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer : Java threats Objects by reference, this means the 2 vars pointing to same memory location.

Now up to some solutions.

First solution is fetching a new Object from the DB as the original object.
But, if you do this => this should be more code for the server and not for the GUI part.

Second solution is to use a [form.](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer's_Reference/MVVM/Data_Binding/Form_Binding)
You are only intressted if some data has changed => the form has a dirtystatus witch you could enable/disable the save button with.
So if the button is enabled you are sure that there are some changes.
If you need to know the exact changes you need to "clone" your object so you can check that out.
But I think the form object resolves your problem of not be able to press the button when no changes are done.

Hope this could help you a little bit.

Comment: I have to know the exact changes. I'm already using the `form` binding (see `editPersonDialog` view code above) so it handles a middle object until the user saves the form. But I need to do the comparison in my `savePerson` method, when the viewmodel property object is already updated. I forgot the point about the copy by reference (although I come from C# where it is the same...) so I will clone my object. I will implement my own `clone()` method as it seems the use of `IClonable` is not considered as a best practice. Thank you chillword it helped a lot ;)

Comment: Maybe you could update the form object after save? Pass the form as bindingparam, like this personen is clean and the changes are in the form object

Comment: Indeed it may be a solution, but doing so I can't manage to save my objects to database, let's say `newPerson` is my binding param, trying to save it directly (`personManager.update(newPerson)`) raises an `unknown entity` exception. Putting the `newPerson` object into the `person` object before saving (`setPerson(newPerson); personManager.update(person)`) raises a `nested form` exception.

Comment: Of course, from ZK8 this could be possible (because the proxy is then also of the object class) but now, you need to iterate over the fields and update person yourself before saving. If you need versioning on DB maybe you could look at http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/

Comment: OK I see. All is fine now thank you for your patience.